# kendo multiple grid on same page data mismatch

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Two ASP MVC Kendo Grid on Single Page.
When I am loading that page my data getting mismatch in between two grid.
My Both Method Calling but when it displays my all data mashed up between two grids.
How to Resolve it ?

can any one help me ?

```
//This is for Grid1
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Alliant.Domain.Model1>()
        .Name("Model1Grid")
        .NoRecords("No record found.")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
           columns.Bound(e => e.Name).Width("10%");
           columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width("10%").Filterable(false);

        })
        .Pageable(p =>
            {
                p.PreviousNext(false);
                p.Numeric(false);
            })
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(Constant.KendoDefaultPageSize)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetDataBySearch", "Model1", new { area = "" }))
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(Model1 => Model1.Id(x => x.Model1ID))
        )
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

    )
//this is for secounf grid on same page
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Alliant.Domain.Model2>()
        .Name("Model2Grid")
        .NoRecords("No record found.")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
           columns.Bound(e => e.Name).Width("10%");
           columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width("10%").Filterable(false);

        })
        .Pageable(p =>
            {
                p.PreviousNext(false);
                p.Numeric(false);
            })
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(Constant.KendoDefaultPageSize)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData2BySearch", "Model2", new { area = "" }))
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(Model2 => Model2.Id(x => x.Model2ID))
        )
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

    )
```

Comment: I've noticed 2 things in your configuration that might cause a problem. Firstly, paging is enabled but both previous/next and numeric buttons are disabled. How is the user supposed to navigate through pages? Also, filtering is not enabled for both grids, but, it is explicitly disabled for the Description column. Nevertheless, check your server response and make sure your service returns the correct data, as I do not seem to notice anything obvious that might cause data mash up.

Comment: You could maybe share the code for your `Model1.GetDataBySearch` and `Model2.GetData2BySearch` controllers?

Comment: All are working good, But when the record bindings to grid once grid record goes to other grids. @GeorgiYankov

Comment: By "record bindings" do you mean [server binding](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serverbinding)? Note that your current grid is configured for remote binding and mixing both bindings is not supported, thus, it might cause unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Arpit I also faces the same issue,

Some time first `request` finishes first then the data map in another grid.

Please check the below solution

1. First you need to set `AutoBind(false)` in both grids. FYI - [Click Me](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder?&_ga=2.126997069.1193416033.1613110112-213440020.1583936689#autobindsystemboolean)

add the below jquery code to your pages and check.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var Model1Grid= $("#Model1Grid").data("kendoGrid");
   var Model2Grid= $("#Model2Grid").data("kendoGrid");

   Model1Grid.dataSource.read().then(function(){
       Model2Grid.dataSource.read();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jishan siddique, Its Working Good For me. As I want.

Comment: Welcome @ArpitPatel, glad to help you.